# First derivative of splines in bayesian model

Tags: r, bayesian, generalized-additive-model, splines, derivative

Inspired by this post https://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2014/05/15/identifying-periods-of-change-with-gams/, I'm trying to identify periods of change in a GAM model, using bayesian inference.

However, I find that my choice of epsilon (the delta difference between two points), is very sensitive to the resulting confidence intervals.   If I choose a really small epsilon, which is what we should want and do, my intervals of the associated first derivative blow up.  If this epsilon is bigger, the intervals are narrower.

I'm using the **method of finite differences**, where we estimate the trend at two points very close to each other, and calculate the difference between those two points to estimate the slope.

I'm clearly missing out on something while calculating the derivatives.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(brms)
library(mgcv)

set.seed(08242019)
dta <- mgcv::gamSim(eg = 4, n = 200, scale = 2)


mod <- brms::brm(
  y ~ s(x2, by = fac), data = dta, 
  chains = 4,
    cores = 4,
    prior = c(
      prior(student_t(3, 0, 1), class = sigma),
      prior(student_t(3, 0, 1), class = sds),
      prior(student_t(3, 0, 1), class = b),
      prior(student_t(3, 0, 5), class = Intercept)
))


epsilon <- 0.1

first <- expand.grid(x2 = seq(0, 0.99, length = 4000),
                    fac = c('1', '2','3'))

second <- expand.grid(x2 = seq(0 + epsilon, 0.99 + epsilon, length = 4000),
                    fac = c('1', '2','3'))

## get predictions
first_preds <- posterior_predict(mod, newdata = first, summary = FALSE, method = "fitted")
second_preds <- posterior_predict(mod, newdata = second, summary = FALSE, method = "fitted")

## calcualte the difference of the predictions  
diff <- (second_preds - first_preds)/epsilon

## using the posterior samples, we calculate the mean and lower and upper quantiles  
mean_finite_diff <- apply(diff, MARGIN = 2,FUN = mean)
lower_finite_diff <- apply(diff, MARGIN = 2,FUN = quantile, prob = 0.025)
upper_finite_diff <- apply(diff, MARGIN = 2,FUN = quantile, prob = 0.975)

data.frame(mean_finite_diff) %>%
  cbind(lower_finite_diff) %>%
  cbind(upper_finite_diff) %>%
  cbind(first) %>%
  ggplot(.,aes(x2, mean_finite_diff, group  = fac)) + geom_smooth(aes(color = fac), se = FALSE) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_finite_diff, 
                                                                                                                  ymax = upper_finite_diff), alpha = 0.05)
```

[image: intervals shaded using epsilon = 0.1]

However, when you decrease the epsilon,

```
epsilon <- 0.0001

first <- expand.grid(x2 = seq(0, 0.99, length = 4000),
                    fac = c('1', '2','3'))

#second <- expand.grid(x2 = seq(0 + epsilon, 0.99 + epsilon, length = 4000),
 #                   fac = c('1', '2','3'))


second <- first %>%
          mutate(x2 = x2 + epsilon)

## get predictions
first_preds <- posterior_predict(mod, newdata = first, summary = FALSE, method = "fitted")
second_preds <- posterior_predict(mod, newdata = second, summary = FALSE, method = "fitted")

## calcualte the difference of the predictions  
diff <- (second_preds - first_preds)/epsilon

## using the posterior samples, we calculate the mean and lower and upper quantiles  
mean_finite_diff <- apply(diff, MARGIN = 2,FUN = mean)
lower_finite_diff <- apply(diff, MARGIN = 2,FUN = quantile, prob = 0.025)
upper_finite_diff <- apply(diff, MARGIN = 2,FUN = quantile, prob = 0.975)


## plot

data.frame(mean_finite_diff) %>%
  cbind(lower_finite_diff) %>%
  cbind(upper_finite_diff) %>%
  cbind(first) %>%
  ggplot(.,aes(x2, mean_finite_diff, group  = fac)) + geom_smooth(aes(color = fac), se = FALSE) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_finite_diff, 
                                                                                                                  ymax = upper_finite_diff), alpha = 0.05)
```

The width of the intervals blow up
[image: Intervals when using a small epsilon = 0.0001]